# Cannot delete Git tags which have special characters

Tags: git

```
$ git tag
+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+
+"feature/04-28_v001-19"+
```

Above git tags not able to delete since + and " exist in the tags.

Comment: Tag1: +"feature/04-28_v001-11"+
Tag2: +"feature/04-28_v001-19"+

Comment: Try `git tag -d '+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+'`.

Comment: Why can't you delete them? What shell are you using?

Comment: I tried with single quotes & double quotes, \ before special characters but no luck.           i am using Git bash and the code is available in Bit Bucket Repository.

Comment: git tag -d $(git tag -l "*v001*") 
git tag -d '+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+'
git tag -d "+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+"
git tag -d "\+"feature/04-28_v001-11"\+"
All commands also not worked

Comment: It worked for me. Please extend your question with the exact command line and the error message that you observe. Put them in a code block so that we do not have to guess where the line breaks are.

Comment: $ git tag -d $(git tag -l "+*")
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+': unable to create directory for .git/refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-19"+': unable to create directory for .git/refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-19"+

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+': unable to create directory for .git/refs/tags/+"feature/04-28_v001-11"+
```

indicates that you are not operating on POSIX. I assume you are on Windows.

As the error message indicates, Git is unable to create a directory containing the doublequote character. The conclusion is that the tag does not exist on the filesystem, but only in the packed-refs file.

**WARNING:** The following suggests a method to fix your problem, but you are messing with Git's database. Be sure to have a backup of the repository before you continue.

Before you continue, be sure the the repository is quiescent. No Git operations must be on-going. Close all UIs including code editors and IDEs that would access the repository.

Now, make a backup of the file

```
.git/packed-refs
```

just in case you break something.

To remove the tag, edit this file with a modern source code editor that can cope with Unix-style line-terminators (LF instead of CRLF) (any editor but Notepad will do). Look up the lines mentioning the tags, and delete the lines and the lines following them if they begin with the caret `^`.

That is, when you start with

```
# pack-refs with: peeled fully-peeled sorted
9e72299d[...] refs/heads/master
57689754[...] refs/tags/bad/one
^b73b6860[...]
03706a09[...] refs/tags/bad/two
^ed20caaf[...]
f9d1d51c[...] refs/tags/good/one
^4974cb42[...]
```

you remove the `bad` ones, you should end with

```
# pack-refs with: peeled fully-peeled sorted
9e72299d[...] refs/heads/master
f9d1d51c[...] refs/tags/good/one
^4974cb42[...]
```

Call `git tag` to verify the result.

Comment: Thank you guys for the different solutions. my issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you guys for the different solutions. my issue resolved manually with NO commands.
Steps:
1. Login to Bit bucket
2. Go to Branch and select Commit option 
3. Select the commit id where the tag is placed with +"feature/04-28_v001-11"+
3. Click on the Commit it will open new window with below options
    Commit id, Branch Name, PR, Tag at Top Right side of the Bit bucket repository 
4. Select Delete Tag option. 
My Issue resolved. 
Tried above all commands but some how it didn't worked for me.